# File count limit for NFS Mounted Drive

Tags: linux, mount

Is there a known upper limit on the number of files one can place in a folder on an NFS mounted drive on 64bit Linux systems? I have come across one excellent [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466521/how-many-files-in-a-directory-is-too-many) that discusses related issues but there appears to be nothing specific to NFS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see how NFS is relevant. The issue here will be the actual file system of the exported partition. The fact that you are mounting it locally via NFS shouldn't make any difference at all, it is the underlying filesystem that needs to deal with the files so you will have the same limits as those mentioned in the SO answer you linked to.

So, as far as I know, there is no limit to the number of files an NFS partition can hold. There are limits for the actual file system, but not for the sharing protocol you use.

Answer (score 2):

The limit would probably be on the remote filesystem not the NFS protocol,
I found these info here: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7722130/what-is-the-max-number-of-files-that-can-be-kept-in-a-single-folder-on-win7-mac

- FAT32 (still used a lot, especially on external media): 65,534
- NTFS:   4,294,967,295
- ext2/ext3 (Linux): Depends on configuration at format time, up to 4,294,967,295 HFS+ (Mac): "up to 2.1 billion"

Answer (score 0):

Big number of small files is usually not a problem for NFS. But it can be a problem for file systems optimized for huge files, for examples Hadoop file system: HDFS.